# How to connect google ads api with php project

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I'm using google ads to generate keywords ,

I'm not sure if i did follow the right instructions.

I created at first a manager account https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/accounts-overview#test_accounts then i apply for test account ( but in my status test account is close) even manager :( and i don't know why.

Teams from google ads said that in their system they are open ...however

When i test my app with developer token and outh2 : i got this message

```
ApiException was thrown with message '{
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "code": 7,
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
        {
            "@type": 0,
            "data": "type.googleapis.com\/google.ads.googleads.v3.errors.GoogleAdsFailure"
        },
        {
            "@type": 0,
            "data": [
                {
                    "errorCode": {
                        "authorizationError": "CUSTOMER_NOT_ENABLED"
                    },
                    "message": "The customer can't be used because it isn't enabled."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}'
```

Do you have experience with google ads api ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually complete your account set up through Google Ads UI

Answer (score -1):

You need to contact Google to get your access fixed, and if I understand you corrfectly you acknowledge your account is not approved. Well that's the problem :-)

That said, make sure that:

- You are using the correct account for API access.
- You are accessing the sandbox, until you get more access.
- You are using all the correct user/account/OAuth values. Double check these.

Until Google approves you, you won't be able to get access. Simple as that.